# What happend to Kaz's T-85 X-wing?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-resistance

We see in first episode of Star Wars: Resistance, that Kaz is a member of New Republic Navy. During fight his T-85 X-wing is being hit and it's taken to Resistance Corvette for repairs.

What happend to this fighter? It was returned somehow to the New Republic Navy or was used later by the Resistance?

Answer (score 2):

The *[Star Wars: The Last Jedi Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary)* reports that it was destroyed, along with every other Resistance T-85, in the Hosnian Cataclysm.

> T-70 X-WING
>
> With **the New Republic's T-85 X-wing fleet atomized by the [destruction of the Hosnian system](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hosnian_Cataclysm)**, the Resistance's T-70s are once again the most advanced examples of this legendary design.

That being said, at least one T-85 survived and was found in the Ibdis Maw, possibly Kaz's but probably not.

> The woman held out a hand and hauled Shriv to his feet. He looked
> around. The payload on the platform was even more spectacular than he
> could have hoped for. A whole freaking platform of X-wings. Four T-70s
> just like he used to fly himself, an older model, T-65B, and one T-85
> looking way too new to scrap for parts.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Resistance Reborn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Resistance_Reborn)</sup></sub>